# Qt application name placeholder

Tags: c++, qt, property-placeholder

In Qt 4.8.6, is there a mechanism to show the value of [`QCoreApplication::applicationName()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop) in the GUI without programming? I mean, is there a set of placeholders which can be used in [`QWidget::windowTitle()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop), [`QLabel::text()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#text-prop) and other properties, that would be replaced by some common strings like application name or version? Something like the `[*]` placeholder in [`QWidget::windowTitle()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop).

Comment: Do mean, how to do this with the QWidget Designer, purely in .ui file?

Comment: Not _purely_, but mainly. I suppose, if such wildcard mechanism exists, it should not matter how I entered the wildcard in the widget's text. The application name or any other replacement text would of course be defined in the code.

Comment: I don't think "wildcard" is a word you want to use here, since it is used for matching something from a collection (such as files in a directory).

Comment: That might be a good point. Is "placeholder" a better term? Isn't it rather connected to HTML? "Macro" doesn't seem to be a suitable word. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I guess I might write "placeholder/macro". The `[*]` is called placeholder, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't an existing mechanism to do that. Fortunately, you can implement your own.

To substitute text in controls, you can use a proxy style that replaces all occurences of "macros" that you specify.

To substitute text in window titles, you have to intercept the `QEvent::WindowTitleChange`.

To make such macros unique, you should wrap them with some [control codes](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch23.pdf): here, US/RS. A complete example follows.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/text-wildcard-40235510
#include <QtWidgets>

constexpr auto US = QChar{0x1F};
constexpr auto RS = QChar{0x1E};

class SubstitutingStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QMap<QString, QString> substs;
public:
    static QString _(QString str) {
        str.prepend(US);
        str.append(RS);
        return str;
    }
    void add(const QString & from, const QString & to) {
        substs.insert(_(from), to);
    }
    QString substituted(QString text) const {
        for (auto it = substs.begin(); it != substs.end(); ++it)
            text.replace(it.key(), it.value());
        return text;
    }
    virtual void drawItemText(
            QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, int flags, const QPalette & pal,
            bool enabled, const QString & text, QPalette::ColorRole textRole = QPalette::NoRole) const override;
};

void SubstitutingStyle::drawItemText(
        QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, int flags, const QPalette & pal,
        bool enabled, const QString & text, QPalette::ColorRole textRole) const
{
    QProxyStyle::drawItemText(painter, rect, flags, pal, enabled, substituted(text), textRole);
}

template <typename Base> class SubstitutingApp : public Base {
public:
    using Base::Base;
    bool notify(QObject * obj, QEvent * ev) override {
        if (ev->type() == QEvent::WindowTitleChange) {
            auto w = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(obj);
            auto s = qobject_cast<SubstitutingStyle*>(this->style());
            if (w && s) w->setWindowTitle(s->substituted(w->windowTitle()));
        }
        return Base::notify(obj, ev);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    SubstitutingApp<QApplication> app{argc, argv};
    auto style = new SubstitutingStyle;
    app.setApplicationVersion("0.0.1");
    app.setStyle(style);
    style->add("version", app.applicationVersion());

    QLabel label{"My Version is: \x1Fversion\x1E"};
    label.setWindowTitle("Foo \x1Fversion\x1E");
    label.setMinimumSize(200, 100);
    label.show();
    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

See also: [control text elision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286216/1329652).

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Just a side note - you use braces instead of parentheses at some places, e.g. right in the beginning, in US/RS definitions. You seem to be using a newer C++ dialect, so just want to make sure that this is correct (some new feature)...?

Comment: @yman If by "newer" you mean 5 years old, then yes, you're right. Old C++ has unfortunately overloaded function calls and object construction using the same syntax. C++11 allows you to decouple them. BTW, you *really* should learn C++11. It's not a new "dialect", it is almost a new programming language, with a bunch of new and concise ways of doing things that were formerly unpleasant or required external libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and explanation. My current project is a desktop app, but generally I work in embedded where a 5 years old language is still quite new and might be problematic. Anyway, I will surely slowly converge to it.

Comment: @yman You might want to listen to this year's [Jason Turner's CppCon 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBkNBP00wJE), then. What he shows does require the newest C++, and is not possible in older standards, nor in C. These days C++ generates better code than C, and that gap will  only be widening over time. If you're using a standard platform like ARM, you can use the newest and greatest.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then [qtTrId](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qtTrId) should help you. It's not a *wildcard*, but you are allowed to choose any `ID` you want.

**Details:**

A few changes should be applied to [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-linguist-hellotr-example.html) example.

1. Use `qtTrId` with `IDs` instead of `tr`, like:

   QPushButton hello(qtTrId("applicationNameId"));
2. In the fifth step [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/linguist-programmers.html#creating-translation-files), you should put `-idbased` parameter to the `lrelease` tool.

   lrelease -idbased hellotr_la.ts

*note: hellotr_la.ts have been generated using `lupdate` in the first step [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/linguist-programmers.html#creating-translation-files)*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've read the function documentation, but don't really understand it, as I've never used the i18n features of Qt. Can you please provide a simple example? Or does it require complex use of the i18n features?